# sed + need to remove each line in file that begin with ###

Tags: sed

How to remove line that begins with three #

For example need to delete all the following lines: from file

1    ### bla bla bal

2    ###blablabla

3    ###       blabla

.
.
.

THX
Yael

Comment: possible duplicate of [sed + delete line that begin with ### include space between line beginning and ###](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3093048/sed-delete-line-that-begin-with-include-space-between-line-beginning-and)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use awk as well

```
awk '!/^[ \t]*###/' file
```

Answer (score 6):

```
cat file | sed '/^###/d'
```

Comment: Well if you try it without it will sit there for a long time ;)

Comment: you pass the file as input to sed. `sed '/^###/d' file`

Comment: We could get into a long discussion of how *nix scripts should always be pipes from STDIN/STDOUT but yes, sed will take one or more file arguments on the command line.

Comment: from my point its better to use the awk but how to change sed in order to do what awk do?

Comment: for example cat file | sed '/^###/d' not effect if some space before the "###"
yael

Comment: @unbeli, and there's no need for input redirection

Comment: @ghostdog74 and there is no need to repeat yourself ;)

Comment: @unbeli, what are you referring to? i am talking about the "<" in `sed ... < file` that you propose. This is technically not the same as `cat file| sed ...`. so which part am i repeating myself?

Comment: @ghostdog74 how is sed < file different from cat file | sed, except sparing some time?

Comment: @yael.  The reason this does not remove lines beginning with spaces or tabs followed by ### is that this was not asked for. You can do that with `sed '/^[\t ]*###/d'` the same as the awk command.

Comment: @everyone. Can we please accept that sed will read input from STDIN (Whether piped or redirected) or from one or more filenames provided as paramaters on the command line. This comment thread is getting silly