# sed + delete line that begin with ### include space between line beginning and ###

Tags: sed

I have:

```
sed -i '/^###/d' file
```

How to change the sed syntax in order to react like awk syntax?

```
awk '!/^[ \t]*###/' file
```

for example sed need to delete line that begin with space or TAB and then `###`?

Comment: I suggest you accept the answer you've got your sed line from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3092219/sed-need-to-remove-each-line-in-file-that-begin-with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed -i '/^[ \t]*###/d' file
```